# Google Gmail account. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host?

Tags: smtp, gmail

Hello Friday Afternoon!

I have been handballed a job in the rough. The following site gets an SMTP error after submitting the form. I have searched around for an answer to this and I still can't resolve the problem?!

http://www.eppinggardens.com.au/enquiry.php

I believe the domain ISN'T blacklisted by gmail (I found some test, that seemingly came back clean). I'm not sure where or even how to check SMTP logs, as the client won't allow me to access the CPANEL/hosting at NetRegistry.

I have emailed NetRegistry suggesting this:
"Contact: Call or email your hosting provider and find out what SMTP server
they provide for outbound relay. Make sure they know you want to use your
@gmail.com address as the From/Reply-to address."

...and I got a very random, non-helpful response from them!

Does anyone have any genius solution as to how I can resolve this please?

cheers
Luke

Comment: The only other bit of info I can offer is its using PHPMailer...
I found this in the "enquiry.php" code
$title = "Email w/PHPMailer + Google's Gmail Service";

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail account for authentication, make sure that you have enabled SSL option in your script and use port 465 for SMTP.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kailash. I found in 'another' file somewhere that was using port 25; I changed that and it still wasn't working. Is there somewhere I should be looking to enable SSL, or is it a line of code I should be adding (and to which file? there seems to be a few)...I can read the PHP, but I'm not great at working out where to put things. Thanks again for your help!